# Unable to get desired google search result using module "google"

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, google-search

i have been trying to scrap google search data. 
Let me explain what i have done so far.

i have used google module to get the search results, with Beautiful soup. Below i have given the sample search i have made,

```
>>> from google import search
>>> 
>>> for i in search("tom and jerry", tld="co.in",num=10,stop=1): print i

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mugo5LoG8Ws
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_and_Jerry
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/debate/article-2390792/How-sense-humour-censor-Tom-Jerry-racist-By-Mail-TV-critic-CHRISTOPHER-STEVENS.html
http://edp.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_and_Jerry
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSK5curwV_o
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb8jTvSwJbw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj8VuTr5q9g
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIprJoPTJoI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaX3hvrZDJA
http://www.cartoonnetwork.com/games/tomjerry/
https://www.facebook.com/TomandJerry/
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2mn36a
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2p0k8j
>>>
```

But this result actually differs from the manual search result.

[image: Manual try of the same query/keyword]

How actually it differs, if we make any changes to the **init**.py file of google library we can get some efficient result?

Please sort me out a possible way..

Thanks in advance.

[Note] : already surfed for previous discussions in stackoverflow. If it is a Dup, I apologize... :)

EDIT 1: Also i get duplicate links sometimes,. First link is repeated few times in the generator output i am getting from google.search(*arg) command. Please advice me how to get rid of this

I got how this DUP came. It is the sublinks shown for the popular websites in google search page. [image]

sorry the pixel was too small. :)

Researching more on the API output and the way the output is parsed. Thanks for all who could have thought of helping me :)